# How to resolve FileStream "Error #3013: File or directory is in use" in Action Script 3?

Tags: file, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, filestream

I know this type of questions are already asked by many users but that didn't resolved my problem.

I am using a FileStream to write some content in a file and following are the codes which i am using to do this :

```
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream ();
fs.open( f , FileMode.WRITE ); // f is contains the file path
fs.writeBytes ( fzf.content ); // fzf is a FZipFile which contains some content
fs.close ();
```

But problem is that initially if I am writing a file then that is working perfectly but without closing the application if I am trying to write another file then that is showing the error "**File or directory is in use**" at line `fs.open`,so I don't know where i am doing wrong as i am calling the `close()` after writing the write method.

If anybody can find where I am doing wrong or how to resolve this problem please help me to solve.

Comment: Not clear if you try it on the same **fs** instance or a new one. Also, providing the links that "didn't resolve your problem" will be a plus.

Comment: Hi @Organis, yes I am trying to write another file using the same FileStream "fs".

Comment: Try the following. Dispose of used **fs** and create a new one. Sometimes re-using things in AS3 is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save the files one after another, right ? If so this error comes up because the files are not closing fast enough before you try to write the next one. You should use the openAsync() instead of open() and listen for the Event.CLOSE event on your Filestream (it is only triggered in the asynchronous mode). When it is triggered you can write the next file:

```
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream ();
fs.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onFileClosed);

fs.openAsync( f , FileMode.WRITE ); // f is contains the file path
fs.writeBytes ( fzf.content ); // fzf is a FZipFile which contains some content
fs.close ();

private function onFileClosed(e:Event):void
{
    // The file was closed succesfully, it is now safe to write the next one
}
```